# What is the probability that a random simple graph on [n] is a tree?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the probability that a random simple graph on [n] is a tree?

Just started probability in combinatorics class, not sure how to tackle this.

Comment: How is a random simple graph defined?  Are you just including edges from $K_n$ with some probability $p$?  If so, is $p=1/2$ or is it unspecified?  Or are you drawing a graph uniformly at random from the set of all simple graphs on $[n]$?

Comment: @saulspatz I believe along the lines of the latter, with the probability being p=1/2 of an edge being included or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about uniformly chosen random graph (same as Erdos-Renyi with $p=1/2$), then there are $n^{n-2}$ labeled trees on $n$ vertices by Cayley's formula (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula ).  The probability of any one of these coming up is $2^{-n(n-1)/2}$, so it's
$$
2^{-n(n-1)/2} n^{n-2}
$$
If you dispose of the "labeled" condition, but are still choosing uniformly, this is the sort of situation where there is almost surely no closed/explicit/useful formula.  However, there are $2^{\binom{n}{2}}/n! (1+o(1)) = 2^{n(n-1)/2}e^{n}n^{-n-1/2}(\sqrt{2 \pi}+o(1))$ graphs (almost all graphs have no nontrivial automorphism + Stirling) and there are $C \alpha^n n^{-5/2} (1+o(1))$ trees on $n$ vertices (Otter 1948), where $\alpha = 2.955765\ldots$ and $C = 0.5349496\ldots$.  Therefore, the probability you seek is
$$
2^{-n^2/2} \beta^n n^{n-2} (C'+o(1))
$$
where $\beta = \sqrt{2} \alpha/e \approx 1.5377667\ldots$ and $C' = C \sqrt{2 \pi} \approx 1.3409198\ldots$.

Comment: How do we arrive at  [-n(n-1)/2].  And once we arrive at this number, we are to multiply this by the total tree possibilities, or we are supposed to divide? Also, n(n-1)/2 looks like n choose 2, but why the added negative sign?

Comment: p := 2^{-n(n-1)/2} = 1/2^{\binom{n}{2}} =: 1/N -- this is the probability of any particular graph coming up, since they're all equally likely and there are 1/p = N of them.  If there is a collection of M graphs and you want to know what the probability of one of them occurring is in this model, it will be M/N = Mp (by linearity of expectation, for example, applied to the sum of the indicator variables for each of the M possibilities).